# Firestore VueJS: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DEADLINE_EXCEEDED')

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension

Given the code on the left part of the first image below, I obtain the error displayed on the second image.

Given the code on the right part of the first image below, I obtain the result I want, which is the creation of a document in my Google Firestore DB.

My objective is to create this document from a call of my browser extension (code on the left part), but I only succeed while making the call from a nodeJS app (code on the right part).

I use:

- NPM 6.14.15 (in both applications)
- nodejs 14.17.6 (in both applications)
- @google-cloud/firestore 4.15.1 (in both applications)
- typescript: 4.1.5 (only in my browser app, code on the left part)
- Chrome Version 86.0.4240.183 (to test my browser extension)

I have followed this documentation https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers#node.js_1.

In order to solve this problem, I have been wondering if it was possible to call the firestore API from a browser environment, but if I read this link properly (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/environments-js-sdk), the answser seems to be yes... I am not sure.

Image 1 (code comparisons, my browser ext. on the left, the node app on the right):

[image]

Image 2 (error of my Chrome extension):

[image]

If you have any idea, advice, solution... Thank you for stopping by.

Comment: The error already tells you the information you need to check which is `getServiceConfig` function in `util.js:143`. You try to read `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` from the undefined variable. For example `foo.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` this means foo is undefined.

Comment: I understand the error, but it occurs in the dependencies I import. I don't think I am supposed to get my hands into it. Also I wonder why it would happen in one application and not the other...

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that you use `@google-cloud/firestore` (Google Cloud Firestore) which is different from `firebase` (Firebase Firestore). I am not familiar with Google Cloud Firestore but from [this](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-mobile-web), it seems you should use `firebase` for the web browser instead.

Comment: I was just reading this when you posted your comment. I agree with you... I will have to use Firebase for this particular usage... Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll validate it, since I think it is the right thing to do... Even though I still don't understand why it wouldn't work :/